# AutoMapper inheritance mapping doesn't work as expected

Tags: automapper

This is `AutoMapper ver3.2.1` installed via `NuGet Package Manager Console`. I tried to implement the inheritance mapping as the formal unit tests demonstrated, but actually it doesn't work.

My code attached as below:

```
public abstract class ModelBase
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
}

public class Model : ModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ModelBaseDto
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public bool UpdateDateSpecified { get; set; }
}

public class ModelDto : ModelBaseDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `Mapping configuration`:

```
      AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ModelBaseDto, ModelBase>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdateDate, opt => opt.Condition(src => src.UpdateDateSpecified))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Guid, opt => opt.Condition(src => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(src.Guid)))
            .Include<ModelDto, Model>();

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ModelDto, Model>();
```

Finally, there is the unit test code segment:

```
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var model = new Model() 
        {
            Guid = "123"
        };

        mapping.Map<ModelDto, Model>(
             new ModelDto()
             {
                 UpdateDate = new DateTime(),
                 UpdateDateSpecified = false,
                 Guid = " ",
                 Name = "Dto"
             }, model);

        Assert.IsFalse(model.UpdateDate.HasValue);
        Assert.AreEqual(model.Guid, "123");
        Assert.AreEqual(model.Name, "Dto", "failed");
    }
```

You will see the 1st and 2nd assertion gets always failed.
If I explicitly add the conditional mapping to the derived class but not the base class, the mapping will act as expected.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is odd. The only thing I can figure is that those properties are counted as "ignored" by the base mapping and are then picked up by the child mapping as described here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance

Comment: But it should not be, please refer to the similar unit test include_should_apply_condition here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/3b9d455eb9b76dd6192c9f88c7a89e4b7dd714d2/src/UnitTests/MappingInheritance/IncludedMappingShouldInheritBaseMappings.cs

Comment: Similar, but not identical. The properties `DifferentBaseString` and `BaseString` on the source and destination types are the main difference, and things work when the names of the properties are different

Comment: Yes, it's really tricky that the single conditional mapping is identified as "Inherited Ignore Property Mapping" and then get the lowest priority. It means at background the conditional mapping was categorized as one kind of ignore mapping. Thank you Andrew, you saved me from headache.

Comment: Maybe misusing `Include`,... in the second mapping you are missing `.IncludeBase<ModelBaseDto, ModelBase>()` more info https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html